# ntpd daemon doesn't start automatically in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, time, ntpd

I wanted to setup ntpd the right way - so not with a crontab entry.

I followed the guide in the [FreeBSD docs](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-ntp.html):

- create an entry with `ntpd_enable="YES"` in /etc/rc.conf
- checked that everything works fine when `service ntpd start` is executed
- restart the machine and checked `service ntpd status`

there I'll get an `ntpd is not running.`

**what am I missing here?**

---

my /etc/rc.conf:

```
hostname="myspecialhostname"
keymap="german.cp850.kbd"
ifconfig_em0="inet 192.168.5.55 netmask 255.255.255.0"
defaultrouter="192.168.5.1"
sshd_enable="YES"
ntpd_enable="YES"
powerd_enable="YES"
dumpdev="AUTO"
zfs_enable="YES"
php_fpm_enable="YES"
apache24_enable="YES"
nfs_client_enable="YES"
```

my /etc/ntp.conf:

```
driftfile /var/db/ntpd.drift

server de.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 0.freebsd.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.freebsd.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.freebsd.pool.ntp.org iburst

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
restrict 127.127.1.0
```

Comment: If it doesn't start and there's nothing about it in any log file, that's either a typing error (number of times I've been searching for what was a letter inversion in config file) or a bug ... I don't see any other reason.

Comment: If you run ntpd manually, does it give you any error messages?

Comment: if I try to start ntpd via "service ntpd start" it doesn't print error messages and doesn'T start either... :(

Comment: I was wrong! ntpd was running but not via "service ntpd start" but via direct start of an manually triggered "ntpd" - that one wasn't listed in "service ntpd status" so I had to kill the running ntpd daemon and now I am able to start ntpd via service...   -   I'll post if it is working after an reboot after the next reboot!

Comment: @Mr.Gosh When I said "run it manually", I should have been clearer - what I meant starting it directly, not from a script and not using `service`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the system on which you are trying to install ntpd has its clock set to within 1000 seconds of the true time. ntpd will give up and produce a message on start if you have verbosity set to, say 10. I assumed that ntpd would correct the time for you, but if the system time is off by a large amount, in my case about 30 minute ... it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable/start also ntpdate. It synchronizes the clock even if the datetime is off by a lot.

```
sysrc ntpdate_enable="YES"
service ntpdate start
```

Cheers!